# Ethernet Cable Unplugged? [Juno]

Tags: networking, release-juno, internet

```
savageholycow@HentaiSavage:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
       logical name: enp4s1
       version: 10
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=32 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d000ff
```

The first thing I can see here is `*-network DISABLED`. Is this probably the reason I can't connect to my BroadBand internet connection? I have switched from Windows 10 to Elementary OS last night. I didn't have a clue what was going on at all. Currently I am using a Mobile Broadband connection which probably won't last more than a day from now. So I really need to be able to connect to my PPPoE/Dial Up connection. Could anyone please help :(

Comment: Just a thought, on my work laptop there is a hard switch to turn the network on or off. You don't have that do you?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? From my experience, when I arrive at work and replug my Lenovo T480 back in to the ethernet (as well as 2 external monitors, through the docking station) via the USB-C after having been online via wifi at home, the `Wired` option on the taskbar is greyed out. I open the network settings and the `Wired` tab says `Cable unplugged`. I have tried restarting the networking-manager as well as >all< the other suggestions found online for ubuntu/elementaryOs but so far the only remedy is to restart my machine. Not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new PPPoE connection in Terminal:
`nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "pppoe"`
`set pppoe.username ******`
`set pppoe.password ******`
`save`
`quit`
Then `nm-connection-editor`, edit ethernet/wired, General tab, uncheck "Automatically connect to this network" for the ethernet/wired connection and leave it only for the PPPoE connection.

Comment: Did all that but no result :( The *-network Disabled thing is still there.

Comment: Can't turn the Wired switch on too

Comment: Do a `sudo service network-manager restart` in terminal.

Comment: Also, make sure that 'Parent interface' and 'PPP interface' are the same in the DSL/PPPoE tab, in the Edit connection window.